# formating iso 8601 to "MMM" and "hourPM/AM" using moment js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, iso8601

I have a date format like:

```
"2021-01-16T03:00:000Z"
```

I want to get something like below out of it using momentJs:

```
Jan 16 - 3am
```

I have written this code but it gives me `invalid date` error (I know the .format() parameter is not my desired date but I'm stuck on getting a valid date out of it in the first step and I can't find which parameter should I pass for my desired format):

```
moment("2021-01-16T03:00:000Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a");
```

How can I get the desired format date with momentJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it the string as `YYYY:MM:DDTHH:MM:SS`:

```js
const getDateFormatted = str => {
  const date = str.slice(0,19);
  return moment(date).format("MMM DD - h a");
}
console.log( getDateFormatted("2021-01-16T03:00:000Z") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**EDIT:** Since OP's expected time is `3am`, and `moment("2021-01-16T03:00:00Z").format("MMM DD - h a")` would give the time as `5am`, it's ok to `split` here. Otherwise, the correct way would be to format the string to the right date without changing the timezone.

Comment: The initial string appears to be UTC, however `str.slice(0,19)` will remove the offset designator so it's parsed as local.

Comment: @RobG OP's expected result requires this implementation, it's stated that ``3am`` not ``5am``

Comment: Where did "5am" come from? The OP wants "2021-01-16T03:00:000Z", which is UTC, to become "something like … Jan 16 - 3am". Parsing it as local means it likely will no longer be 03:00 UTC. The shift in timezone should be pointed out in the answer. An alternative that doesn't shift the timezone is to use the [*utc* method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Comment: @RobG you're right, this needs more clarification, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
const a = moment("2021-01-16T03:00:00Z")
let   b = a.format("MMM Do [-] h a")
// MMM Do [-] h a
console.log(b)
```

You had a one more 0 that he want : 2021-01-16T03:00:00[0]Z

Comment: I get "invalid date" again!